# Simplest way to simulate basic diffusion over a 3D matrix?

Tags: c++, opencl, physics

I'm currently writing a program that will simulate in very basic terms the diffusion and pressure of a gas in a 3D volume with boundaries throughout - Think for example an ant cave.
The effects I want to achieve:
1. Gas diffuses throughout the environment over time, respecting walls.
2. I'd like to measure pressure, or the compression of the gas, per grid point. The effect of this should be that if a room is opened the gas will diffuse out of the opening in a speed that reflects the pressure difference.

My problem is that I lack the knowledge to fully understand theoretical math equations, and to be honest I'm really not looking for an accurate simulation. I'd just want to achieve some of the prominent effects of the physics at play. I'm not interested in fluid dynamics (For example the simulation of smoke).

I'll be writing this program in OpenCL but happy to take any form of code examples, be it C or pseudo code.

I'm thinking I should pass in 3 3D arrays - One for the gas, one that defines the walls (eg 1 at xyz = wall), and one to store the pressure.
I'm currently assuming checking for the wall is easy enough. One simply checks each neighbour cell for it and account for the cell if its not a wall:

```
For each grid point,
  is wallmatrix[x+1] a wall?
    [diffusion math here]
  is wallmatrix[x-1] a wall?
    [diffusion math here]
  is wallmatrix[y+1] a wall?
    [diffusion math here]
  etc...
```

But I'm just not sure what to do with the diffusion math, nor how I would include pressure in all this?

Comment: ArrayFire supports 3D arrays as well as all of the functions I would imagine you need for this, such as indexing, 3D elementwise diffs, reductions, etc. I work on ArrayFire and have seen other people use it for diffusion/gas physics problems. There is an OpenCL version out now (http://accelereyes.com/arrayfire). Good luck!

Comment: ArrayFire looks interesting. Are you able to point me towards any resources that show ArrayFire doing anything similar to what I require?

Comment: Here are some similar domain problems, look at the shallow-water equations and the FDTD examples here:  https://www.accelereyes.com/arrayfire/c/examples.htm (swe.cpp and fdtd.cpp).  The boundary conditionals would be added with appropriate indexing (https://www.accelereyes.com/arrayfire/c/group__indexing.htm) as you have in your pseudo-code.

Answer (score 2):

Diffusion is one of the easiest things to simulate because it's self smoothing.

For example, you could run your simulation in terms of constant time steps and keeping track of the individual particle positions, and at each time step move each particle a fixed (small) distance, but in a random direction.

There are other ways too, for example, you can do a grid based approach, where change the number of particles in each grid location.

A slight issue with your question is where you say, "diffuse out of the opening in a speed that reflects the pressure difference".  Diffusion doesn't really do this, since diffusion is just the random motion of particles.  I think, though, that even straight diffusion might look satisfying to you here, since the gas will diffuse out of an opening, and it will look faster.  Really what will be happening though is that it will be diffusing out at the same speed as everywhere else, it's just that nothing will be diffusing back in.  Still, if this isn't satisfying, then you will need to get into fluid dynamics, at least a bit, since this is how one describes how fluid behaves when there's a pressure gradient, not diffusion.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example of how you would diffuse a gridpoint in a 3D volume? I intend to use a grid and not particles.

Comment: A simple grid based approach is, for each cell, take a fraction of the value in that cell and put it into neighboring cells, and do this repeatedly.  The amount that you move will determine the rate of diffusion.  For example, say you disperse 10% of the value in each timestep, and you start with 2.20 in a cell.  Then after one timestep, then each of the 6 neighbors will get 2.20*0.1/6 add to them, and the cell will be left with 2.20*0.9 (plus whatever it would get from its neighbors).  (If your programming environment has a convolution, it's a good way to implement this.)

Comment: I understand the math there. Looks good and simple. Wondering if you can expand a little on what you mean by convolution? Also, should I have a double-buffered grid? What I mean by that is should I have a copy of the 3D grid that you place the new values on to on one pass, then swap the new 3D grid for the old one. I understand this will stop the diffusion from effectively happening twice per grid point in a single pass. Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, for whatever you do it's easiest to use a double buffered grid.  Also, physically this makes sense because diffusion is happening everywhere at the same time.  For the convolution, there are many sources that describe how the two relate.  For example, this pdf ( http://www.cs.umd.edu/~djacobs/CMSC828seg/Diffusion.pdf ) shows how to disperse at each timestep (as I described above) in the middle of the last page.  If using a convolution doesn't mean much to you, I'd just skip the idea and program it yourself since it's not hard.

Comment: To be honest I can't understand the math syntax in that paper - I know, I need to learn how to ASAP. Thanks for the resources. I think I have enough to go on with to make what I originally required.
If you'd like to directly answer my question in your original post by adding the equation in any form of code I'll accept the answer. Adding convolution is optional but you'll get bonus internet points. ;)

Comment: I'm not really recommending reading the paper I linked to, it's just a math based explanation of a convolution, but that's only useful if you already know the math.  Instead, I'd suggest you look around, eg google, for information about convolutions that makes sense to you.  There's a lot out there.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not an easy task!

First of all: you want to simulate basic diffusion OR the complete motion of the gas? The second case isn't easy at all, but you can get an idea [here](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch38.html).

If you just want to diffuse a gas in an static environment, things are easier but you can't measure the 
total pressure, your only variable will be the local concentration of the gas.

This phenomena is governed by the [Fick laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fick%27s_law); the second one is probably what you are looking for.

Read for [finite difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) methods to understand how to discretize the diffusion equation.
The subject is quite big to write a complete answer here.

Comment: Thanks for replying. As noted in the original post I'm not interested in fluid dynamics as a whole. Like you mentioned, I'd like to simulate diffusion in a static environment. I understand your point about pressure - I would be happy to have some from of crude estimate such as the exact same diffusion method for the pressure volume. That or I just use localized 'static pressure'?
Regarding your links - Unfortunately I have a real hard time breaking down those math formulas into practical code in 3D.